# Trace apache server activity for a specific http request

Tags: apache-httpd, http, tracing

I have a cracker serving fake content to google bot from my Drupal site. They are able to generally bypass my CMS system but bootstrap it just enough catch http request and return a "cloned" page with injected content from their own CDN. 
Like this one.

```
2016-12-16 05:29:43 Error   66.249.64.109   404 GET /IRVW8pIT HTTP/1.1
```

I do not believe they have gotten INTO my cms.

I can't figure out what piece of code/file is intercepting the http request and routing them against my will. Is there a way to trace what is happening in YOUR OWN server when a specific HTTP request is made?

Comment: Use burpsuite to analyze http requests

Comment: What you have is a "cracker", not a hacker. I am a hacker. There is a [difference](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/it-security/hacker-vs-cracker/)

Comment: appologies, a cracker then